# SWI-Prolog Editor for OS X

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I was searching for a SWI-Prolog editor for Mac OS X but i could not find one, so is there one or do I have to use another editor to build Prolog files?

Thanks

Comment: You ask about an editor but you also write "to build" Prolog files, which suggests that you're looking instead for an IDE. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not use mac OS-X myself, but there are two very good SWI-Prolog editors that are cross-platform (thus also work on OS-X):

- **PDT** works with the Eclipse IDE. It has good syntax coloring, an in-IDE Prolog console, a dynamically generated visualization of the call graph, to name only a few of the many features it has. See http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs/v2.1/start I believe refactoring of Prolog code is not there yet, but the developers plan to add that cool feature in the future as well.
- **PCE Emacs**, an Emacs implementation by Jan Wielemaker that uses SWI-Prolog's graphical library XPCE. The UI elements look very Windows '95-ish, but don't be fooled by mere appearances here. PCE Emacs is completely tuned to SWI-Prolog and is probably the most versatile editor for SWI-Prolog out there. You can simply run it from within the SWI-Prolog console by typing `emacs.`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're considering not only IDEs but also text editors, the Logtalk distribution includes support for a large number of text editors that is also usable for editing Prolog source code. See https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/coding for a list of all supported text editors.

Answer (score 1):

I use OS X and work in Emacs with [prolog-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrologMode).

> This version has all the features one would expect, including syntax highlighting, auto indent, and full interaction with an inferior Prolog process. The mode supports in principle any Prolog system, though it is primarily maintained with SWI Prolog in mind.

It lacks many of the features of PCE Emacs, but has all of the features of GNU Emacs, and I'm pretty happy with it.