# SWI prolog in Xcode5

Tags: xcode5, swi-prolog

How do I write a SWI-Prolog program on Xcode 5? If Xcode does not support Prolog I can execute it through terminal, but which file format of Xcode should I use for writing the code.

Comment: I don't know about Xcode, but you can use [a dedicated SWI-Prolog editor on OS-X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972810/swi-prolog-editor-for-os-x). Also, Paulo seems to have worked on [support for Xcode](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/coding/xcode).

Comment: There are many tutorials and educational material on other websites. Stackoverflow aims to help with problems with software, not general issues as in your question. See the **Help** link at the top of the page to learn about what can be asked about here and how to write a good question.

Comment: What's the point of using Xcode for Prolog programming? None that I'm aware. You've much better support for text editors such as TextMate.